# a complex computing of the average value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

This is my first question on this forum.

I am conducting experiments in which I measure the current-voltage curve of a device applying different experimental conditions.

The different experimental condition are encoded into a parameter `K`

I am performing measurements of the current `I` using **back & forth** voltage sweeps with `V` varying from O to 2V then from 2V to -2V and then back to 0V.

Measurements are conducted several times for each value of `K`to get an average of the current at each voltage point (backward and forward values). Each measurement is ascribed to a parameter named `iter` (varying from 0 to 3 for instance).

I have collected all data into a pandas dataframe `df` and I am putting below a code able of produce the typical `df`I have (the real one is way too large):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

K_col=[]
iter_col=[]
V_col=[]
I_col=[]
niter = 3
V_val = [0,1,2,1,0,-1,-2,-1,0]
K_val = [1,2]
for K in K_val:
    for it in range(niter):
        for V in V_val:
            K_col.append(K)
            iter_col.append(it+1)
            V_col.append(V)
            I_col.append((2*K+np.random.random())*V)
d={'K':K_col,'iter':iter_col,'V':V_col,'I':I_col}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I would like to compute the average value of `I` at each voltage and compare the impact of the experimental condition `K`.

For example let's look at 2 measurements conducted for K=1:

```
df[(df.K==1)&(df.iter.isin([1,2]))]
```

output:

```
    K iter  V      I
0   1   1   0   0.000000
1   1   1   1   2.513330
2   1   1   2   4.778719
3   1   1   1   2.430393
4   1   1   0   0.000000
5   1   1   -1  -2.705487
6   1   1   -2  -4.235055
7   1   1   -1  -2.278295
8   1   1   0   0.000000
9   1   2   0   0.000000
10  1   2   1   2.535058
11  1   2   2   4.529292
12  1   2   1   2.426209
13  1   2   0   0.000000
14  1   2   -1  -2.878359
15  1   2   -2  -4.061515
16  1   2   -1  -2.294630
17  1   2   0   0.000000
```

We can see that for experiment 1 (iter=1) V goes multiple times at 0 (indexes 0, 4 and 8). i do not want to loose these different datapoints.

the first data point for `I_avg` should be  `(I[0]+I[9])/2` which would correspond to the first measurement at 0V. The second data point should be `(I[1]+I[10])/2` that would correspond the the avg_I measured at 1V with increasing values of V etc...up to  `(I[8]+I[17])/2` which would be my last data point at 0V.

My first thought was to use the `groupby()` method using `K` and `V` as keys but this wouldn't work because `V` is varying back & forth hence we have duplicate values of `V` for each measurements and the groupby would just focus on unique values of `V`.

The final dataframe I would like to have should looks like this:

```
    K   V   avg_I
0   1   0   0.000000
1   1   1   2.513330
2   1   2   4.778719
3   1   1   2.430393
4   1   0   0.000000
5   1   -1  -2.705487
6   1   -2  -4.235055
7   1   1   -2.278295
8   1   0   0.000000
9   1   0   0.000000
10  2   1   2.513330
11  2   2   4.778719
12  2   1   2.430393
13  2   0   0.000000
14  2   -1  -2.705487
15  2   -2  -4.235055
16  2   1   -2.278295
17  2   0   0.000000
```

Would anyone have an idea on how doing this?

Comment: Could you elaborate more what you mean when you say that "V is varying back & forth hence we have duplicate values of V for each measurements and the groupby would just focus on unique values of V". Maybe adding an example

Comment: When measuring I vs V, the voltage ramp is going from 0V->2V->-2V->0V with +/-1V steps, hence the V column contains mutiple occurences of each voltage value and cannot serve as an index

Comment: Actually the I-V curve is supposed to behave differently for increasing V values than for decreasing ones. This is why I cannot use V as an index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to compute the mean taking into consideration also the position of each observation during the iterations you could add an extra column containing this information like this:

```
len_iter = 9
num_iter = len(df['iter'].unique())
num_K = len(df['K'].unique())

df['index'] = np.tile(np.arange(len_iter), num_iter*num_K)
```

And then compute the group by and mean to get the desired result:

```
df.groupby(['K', 'V', 'index'])['I'].mean().reset_index().drop(['index'], axis=1)
```

```
    K    V          I
0   1   -2  -5.070126
1   1   -1  -2.598104
2   1   -1  -2.576927
3   1    0   0.000000
4   1    0   0.000000
5   1    0   0.000000
6   1    1   2.232128
7   1    1   2.359398
8   1    2   4.824657
9   2   -2  -9.031487
10  2   -1  -4.125880
11  2   -1  -4.350776
12  2    0   0.000000
13  2    0   0.000000
14  2    0   0.000000
15  2    1   4.535478
16  2    1   4.492122
17  2    2   8.569701
```

Comment: Sounds great Giulio! Many thanks. I just had to reindex the values by increasing values of the `index`column before droping it, otherwise data points were not in the right order. I've been usinf the following command line `df = simu.groupby(['K', 'V', 'index'])[I'].mean().reset_index().sort_values(by='index').drop(['index'], axis=1)
`

Comment: Nice, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to have a new datapoint that represents the average I for each V category. We can achieve this by getting the average value of I for each V and then map it on the full dataframe.

```py
avg_I = df.groupby(['V'], as_index=False).mean()[['V', 'I']]
df['avg_I'] = df.apply(lambda x: float(avg_I['I'][avg_I['V'] == x['V']]), axis=1)
df.head()
```

output:

```
    K   iter    V   I       avg_I
0   1   1       0   0.00    0.00
1   1   1       1   2.34    3.55
2   1   1       2   4.54    6.89
3   1   1       1   2.02    3.55
4   1   1       0   0.00    0.00
```

```
df.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi drake, many thanks for this reply. This is almost it but not exactly what I want. I would like to have the average I for each V on the different measurement 'iter'. Then I would like to compare these series [V,avg_I] with respect to the different K parameters. I am afraid that using groupby('V') would drop half of the values of V since V is going back & forth and cannot serve as an index.